# How to fetch selected dates from jquery datePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datepicker

In my App,we are rendering `DatePicker(calender)` with the following code.It's coming perfectly.

```
 $('#date2').DatePicker({
    flat: true,
    date: [],
    current: '2008-07-31',
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    calendars: 1,
    mode: 'multiple',
    starts: 0
});
```

After I render,it's coming like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qvw8l3lx6i2ni5/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-24%2013:28:12.png).Still Html guy not yet implemented `CSS`.From the calendar user can select multiple dates.

we are using `Backbone and Marionette` in Application.What I want If user select any date from calender, needs to fire an event inside the callback function wants to `console` selected dates().For This I tried with following code but it's not working.

```
events:{
  "select #date2":"consoleDates"
},
consoleDates:function(event){
 console.log($(event.target).val());
}
```

Also I tried with `change` event,This is also not firing.

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you really want to use this plugin, it won't fire any DOM events.  Because this plugin is little dated, I think the concept of CustomEvents haven't been introduced yet.  Anyway, you would have to actually bind a custom event in the instantiation of the code.  So it should look like so:

```
$('#date2').DatePicker({
    flat: true,
    date: [],
    current: '2008-07-31',
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    calendars: 1,
    mode: 'multiple',
    starts: 0,
    onChange: function(formatted, dates){
       $('#date2').trigger('datePick', arguments);
    }
});
```

Then in Backbone it should look like so:

```
events:{
  "datePick #date2":"consoleDates"
},
consoleDates:function(event, formatted, dates){
  console.log(formatted.join(', '));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onselect. Try this:

```
 $('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(date) {
       alert(date);
   }
 });
```

Update: Looking at the doc, the property for this is `onChange`:

```
onChange: function(formated, dates){
    console.log(dates);
}
```

Comment: simply I ran your code in `console`,it's showing an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. So for my testing I ran `$('.selector')` it's returning `[]`.

Comment: why would you run the code in console. and which datepicker you are using

Comment: I am using `multiple-select` calender.You can see http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/